# php null object given by IE but other working correct

Tags: php, javascript, flash, object, action

there is a problem with IE browser it does not recognize object HTMLEmbedElement and not proceed for further execution .
i have no choice because there is nothing to be updated in programming code 
how can i fix this browser issue please help

Answer (score 0):

IE uses `<object>` elements, not `<embed>` elements.  Read up on the `<object>` tag, which is better supported across browsers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to write the code like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="1000" height="303" id="FinalHeader.swf" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="movie" value="FinalHeader.swf" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed src="FinalHeader.swf" play="true" loop="true" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="1000" height="303" name="FinalHeader.swf" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

You put an `<embed>` tag *inside* the object tag~ browsers that don't like one will use the other.